# Xcode stops at the end of file when using Ctrl+F, instead of starting again

Tags: ios, xcode

I know there is an option somewhere in Xcode to tell it to whenever I'm finding something with Ctrl+F and reaches the end of document by hitting Enter (because I already went through all matching words), go back again to the first matching word.

I've installed Xcode in a new Mac and whenever I reach the end of document when finding it just stops and displays what you see on the attached screenshot:

[image: img]

Comment: Do you mean cmd+f instead of ctrl+F, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the magnifier icon on the left of the search field and select "Edit Find Options...":
[image: Select "Edit Find Options..."]

Check the "Wrap" option:
[image: Check "Wrap"]